# AIX - XercesC runtime error: a runtime definition of the symbol was not found

Tags: c, runtime-error, aix, undefined-symbol, xerces-c

I am using xercesc functions in my code. When the code is compiled, it compiles successfully. But at runtime (only on AIX, LINUX just works perfectly on same CMakeFiles) with an error as below:

> Could not load program mymodule: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol
>   _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE was referenced from module mymodule(), but a runtime definition of the symbol was not
>   found.

I checked the in dbx, and whatis gives me below.

```
(dbx) whatis _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE 
&_ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE = 0x0005665b
```

I also checked the library libxerces-c.a in dbx and whatis gives me below:

```
(dbx) whatis _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE
_ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE (0x004fa38c):
```

LIBPATH is pointing to the location where libxerces-c.a is kept.

Can someone point me out what is missing here?

Xerces-C version : 2.8.0
Aix-7.1.0.0

Comment: The human readable format is `xercesc_2_8::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale`. You should examine your `mymodule` program regarding the external symbols... You could start with `dump -Tv -X32_64 mymodule`

Comment: Hi @LorinczyZsigmond , I tried running the dump for mymodule, fgXercescDefaultLocale is shown as EXTref and library is correctly mentioned as libxerces-c.a.  ``dump -Tv -X32_64 mymodule | grep _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE
[256]   0x00000000    undef      IMP     RO EXTref   libxerces-c.a _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE
``The libxerces-c.a is in location pointed by ``$LIBPATH`` and dump command on the lib shows function as defined ``
[350]   0x104fa38c    .text      EXP     RO   Ldef        [noIMid] _ZN11xercesc_2_86XMLUni22fgXercescDefaultLocaleE
``

Comment: Did you compile this `Xerces-C` yourself, or downloaded it from somewhere? (If the latter, please give the URL.)

Comment: I had compiled this ``>cd $BUILD_AREA/COMMON/Xerces-c_2_8_0/src/xercesc
>XERCESCROOT=$BUILD_AREA/COMMON/Xerces-c_2_8_0
>export XERCESCROOT
>./runConfigure -p aix -d 
>gmake
``